# Why the Instance<Object> is null?

Tags: java, postconstruct

I have the following structure:

```
public class StringFactory {
    @Inject
    private Instance<StringFormatter> formatterInstances;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for (AddressFormatter formatter : formatterInstances) {
            System.out.println("String formater: " + formatter);
        }
    }
 }
```

StringFormatter

```
interface StringFormatter {

    String createFormattedString(final String x);
}
```

StringFormaterForKR

```
public class StringFormaterForKR implements StringFormatter {

    @Override
    public String createFormattedString(String x) {
        return null;
    }
```

DefaultStringFormater

```
public class DefaultStringFormater implements StringFormatter {

    @Override
    public String createFormattedString(String x) {
        return null;
    }
```

Test

```
public class Test() {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      StringFactory factory = new StringFactory(); 
    }     
}
```

I don't understand why formatterInstances is null ?
And I saw that the message from PostConstruct is never printed...

Do you have any explication for this ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be non-null?

Comment: I tought that it will have: DefaultStringFormatter and StringFormaterForKR

Comment: Why did you think that?

Comment: I saw that Instance it is an Iterable and those two classes implements StringFormatter..

Comment: Why would `formatterInstances` be non-null? What's initializing it?

Comment: The @Inject annotation ?

Comment: Annotations aren't magic. What part of your code is handling the `@Inject` annotation?

Comment: Injects only the Instance<StringFormatter>... 
But what do I have to do for DefaultStringFormatter and StringFormatterForKR to be injected as well?

Comment: Nothing is injecting anything in your code, which is why your field is `null`. You've written `new StringFactory()`. Where does injection happen there? What's performing the injection?

Comment: I don't know....

Comment: What IoC container did you plan to use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224100/discussion-between-ela-ela-and-savior).